# Dell 1558 I/O error + System crashing

Tags: laptop, bsod, dell-studio, io

I have a Dell Studio 1558 (Core i7, 6G Ram, 500G HD, ATi HD5470) (Not more than a few months old - still in warranty)

Some events that started happening with my laptop starting a few days ago in chronological leading to final problem:

**A few days ago:** I got a BSOD and it restarted. I got a couple more BSODs in that day. I thought that the graphics driver was acting up again - so I left it to itself, not much of a problem.

**Two days back:** The rate of crashing increased suddenly - the BSODs were pointing out the error as `IRQL_NOT_LESS_THAN_EQUAL` **or** `BAD_POOL_DATA` **or** `PAGED_DATA_IN_NONPAGED_POOL`

**Yesterday:** Windows went into a boot-and-restart loop everytime at the login screen. I did the same in safe-mode. Although my Ubuntu installed parallely using WUBI was working fine and booting up great. I thought of formatting and started it using my Dell's Win7 DVD. And much the surprise, it crashed even in the installer, sometimes just during the beginning of copying files, and then later as I rebooted more and more times - the BSODs started coming more and more.

**Today:** I tried installing another source of Win7 - same result, although this time around, I was told by the system that it no longer recognised my battery variant, so pulled the battery out, now on AC only. Then I tried installing Ubuntu - but it too gave an error that there was an I/O error (Error No. 5) and the files could not be copied to the hardisk due to a faulty hard-disk.

**Now:** I took out the HDD, formatted it at my friend's computer, ran `CHKDSK /f` and put it back - but the problem persists.

**Initial Diagnosis:** I think the problem lies with the HDD, I don't know what.

**Question:** How do I resolve this problem? I am yet to call the service center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run the Dell Hardware Diagnostics](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/xlob/dtg/en/troubles.htm#wp1101057)

If Diagnostics will not run from the hard drive, [download this utility](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&deviceid=3841&libid=13&releaseid=R271134&vercnt=2&formatcnt=0&SystemID=STUDIO1558&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&catid=-1&dateid=-1&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&impid=-1&checkFormat=true) to make a boot CD/DVD or thumbdrive to run diagnostics.

Record any error codes, these will be helpful when asking for a warranty repair from Dell.

[Dell main page for the 1558](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/entry?)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. I discovered that the RAM was faulty.